# Show that function has the form of sech function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there an easy way to verify that
$$
u(x)=\frac{4KC^2\exp(-2Kx)}{(1+\frac{C^2}{2K} \exp(-2Kx))^2} = -2K^2\operatorname{sech}^2(Kx+x_0),
$$
where
$$
\exp(x_0)=(2K)^{1/2}C?
$$

I started with determining the denominator:
$$
\begin{align*}
(1+\frac{C^2}{2K}\exp(-2Kx))^2&=1+\frac{C^2\exp(-2Kx)}{K} + \frac{K^4\exp(-4Kx)}{4K^2}\\
&=\frac{4K^2+4KC\exp(-2Kx)+K^4\exp(-4Kx)}{4K^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Your use of `\text{sech}` rather than `\operatorname{sech}` was the reason why the horizontal spacing to the left of that symbol was smaller than it should be.

Comment: My edit was for a typo: The missing brackets around $Kx+x_0$ on the far right of the 1st line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT. For the denominator $D$ we have $$D=[1+\exp(-2x_0)\exp(-2Kx)\,]^2=$$ $$=4\exp (-2Kx-2x_0)\cdot\left(\frac {\exp (Kx+x_0)+\exp (-Kx-x_0)\,}{2}\right)^2=$$ $$=4\exp (-2Kx-2x_0)\cdot \cosh^2 (Kx+x_0).$$ So what is $\frac {1}{D}$?